# Advanced user management needed

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-login

I need to develop a website using Wordpress.

I am familiar with Wordpress, however I need to install a plugin that allows user to register and login, in order to view personal info.

Can you recommend a plugin or some of them?

The website needs to include a user-management feature, with the following characteristics:

- Enable prospective members to register online and provide their details (title, first_name, last_name, address_1, address_2, address_3, city, post_code, date_of_birth, gender, telephone_number, mobile_number).
- Login into website using customer identification code provided by S.Provider (customer_id, a 10-digit security code made up of their date of birth in XXMMYY format, plus a unique 4-digit number provided by S.Provider).
- Verify their identify by answering a system challenge that comes in two forms:

  - Something we know: Provide the numbers in their 4-digit security code in the order requested by the system (security_code is a unique numeric and 4-digits long, provided by S. Provider)
  - Something they know: Provide 4 out of 9 of characters from their password, in the order requested by the system (password is an alphanumeric of 9 characters, the first of which must not start with a number. This password is chosen by the member).
- Account Summary View page(s): one of more pages containing private details for each registered customer.

Comment: I'm not sure why people persist in using WordPress to put together this sort of thing. It's technically possible, but you'd be better off using a system designed for full CMS stuff like Drupal.

Comment: thank you ceejayoz, I do agree with you. Unfortunately this was not my choice, I have been made using Wordpress strictly.

Comment: Chances are you'll need to do a good chunk of custom coding, then.

Comment: “Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.” [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)